# Unable to convert rest assured test to karate test

Tags: karate, rest-assured

I am trying to migrate one of api test to karate framework. However I am unable to write the corrent step defined in karate documentation. Maybe I am missing some basic syntax..but could anyone have any idea how we write following steps in karate feature

```
    requestPostDoc.header("x-api-key","FG6dcYHN9N7PYKfWCUlGo5QGTwZhv2Re1MrDSOTV");//New chnages
    requestPostDoc.contentType("multipart/form-data").multiPart("part2-file",file).formParam("part1-json",objDocumentWrite.toJSONString());
    requestPostDoc.queryParam("loadProperties",true); //New changes
    responseForNewCaseDocFile=requestPostDoc.post("https://vrh0oox3hl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/");//New changes
    filterableRequestSpecification = (FilterableRequestSpecification) requestPostDoc;
    filterableRequestSpecification.removeQueryParam("loadProperties");
```

I have written following feature file in karate:

```
Given url 'https://vrh0oox3hl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/'
And header x-api-key = 'FG6dcYHN9N7PYKfWCUlGo5QGTwZhv2Re1MrDSOTV'
And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + jwt
And param loadProperties = true
And multipart file info = { read: 'classpath:testData/documentWrite.json', filename: 'documentWrite.json' }
And multipart file Uploading = { read: 'classpath:testData/TextFile.txt', filename: 'TextFile.txt' }
When method post
Then print response
Then status 200
```

When I execute this test i am getting 400 response code

> status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 252, url: https://vrh0oox3hl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/?loadProperties=true, response:

Comment: multi-part is hard, so you need to understand how exactly to form the request. be prepared to do some research and read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: @PeterThomas: So by chance can you please tell me where I am going wrong, because from above link I am writing the correct steps. Can we pass multipart field or something else.

Comment: the point is that I cannot unless I know what your server expects. I can try help if you can add a cURL request that works to your question.

Comment: @PeterThomas :                                                                                                          
 curl --location --request POST 'https://vrh0oox3hl.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/' \
--header 'x-api-key: FG6dcYHN9N7PYKfWCUlGo5QGTwZhv2Re1MrDSOTV' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer tokenkey' \
--form 'part1-json=@"/D:/Users/bakh/Automation/DMS/karate-DMS/src/test/java/testData/documentWrite.json"' \
--form 'part2-file=@"/D:/Users/bakh/Automation/DMS/karate-DMS/src/test/java/testData/TextFile.txt"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `cURL` command in the comments, this is my *best* guess. The rest is up to your research. Read the docs and tweak the `Content-Type` and other sub-headers if needed. *You* need to figure this out depending on what your server wants: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multipart-file

```
* multipart file part1-json = { read: 'documentWrite.json' }
* multipart file part2-file = { read: 'TextFile.txt' }
```

For anyone coming across this question in the future and if you are stuck, get a friend if needed and go through this exercise together: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

This stuff can be hard and needs time. There are no short cuts.

Comment: I will going through the issue https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/797

Comment: I found that  karate code base is referring to older spring-web implementation as I can see content-disposition  instead of Content-Disposition in request. I am working with karate 1.1.0, so is this issue is fixed or not. Sorry for asking multiple questions

Comment: @abdulkhan lower-case should NOT be an issue, if it is - karate has succeeded in finding a bug in your server. at least that's my opinion. "as far as I know" 1.1.0 should work :) look - if you are not able to follow the troubleshooting guide I provided in my answer, the only other suggestion I have is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue